# No enclosing instance of the type OuterClass.StaticNestedClass is accessible in scope

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

I am still learning and currently trying to implement DoublyLinkedLists with nested STATIC classes and getting the error below:

`No enclosing instance of the type OuterClass.StaticNestedClass is accessible in scope`
Actual error: 
`No enclosing instance of the type SolutionDLL.Node is accessible in scope`

I have two **STATIC** nested classes inside the outer class `SolutionDLL` class:

```
class SolutionDLL {
    public static class Node {
        private Object element;
        private Node   next;
        private Node   previous;

        Node(Object elementIn, Node nextNodeIn, Node prevNodeIn) {
            element = elementIn;
            next    = nextNodeIn;
            previous = prevNodeIn;
        }

        public Object getElement() {
            return element;
        }

        public Node getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public Node getPrevious() {
            return previous;
        }

    }

    public static class DLList {
        public void addFirst(Node n) {
            SolutionDLL.Node tempNode = new SolutionDLL.Node(
                SolutionDLL.Node.this.getElement(),
                SolutionDLL.Node.this.getNext(), 
                SolutionDLL.Node.this.getPrevious()); 
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

No matter if i call like this:
`SolutionDLL.Node.this.getElement()` 
of like this: 
`Node.this.getElement()`

I still get the error. I had the skeleton code given and this is the first time I am implementing with nested classes. So any help would be well appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The syntax you are using only works with inner classes. There are no inner classes here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SolutionDLL.Node`, just like any class, does not have `this` field. `this` field is only available inside object and its inner classes of that object class.

Change `addFirst` to get the values fomr `n` node instead:

```
public static class DLList {
   private Node firstNode = null;

    public void addFirst(Node n) {

        //do something with the first node before it is assigned to the n
        if (firstNode != null){
            SolutionDLL.Node tempNode = new SolutionDLL.Node(
            firstNode.getElement(),
            firstNode.getNext(), 
            firstNode.getPrevious()); 
         }
         firstNode = n;
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that I want to replace the original FirstNode with the node passed in the method, that's why i tried doing it this way. How do I access the original Node then? I need to somehow access the previous firstNode before replacing it with the `n` in the method.

Comment: The method is invoked on DLList and not the Node itself. You are not keeping reference to the first node. You have to think it terms of objects and not classes. See my updated code, that hopefully answers your issue.

Comment: Oh okay, I see, i'll try to do it this way then. Thanks! :)